# I have an activity that has navigation menu, and I need to change the colour of active cell from Maroon to Orange. How?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My code is similar to this:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

The color of active cell here is Maroon however I need to make it Orange. Please help me out...

Comment: Have you tried changing `android:listSelector` on `ListView`?

Comment: Can you post your code here, because eventually this site might be  closed) You need to add the question to the post

Comment: You should post *your* code, the code at the link is under copyright.

Answer (score 0):

change the list_item_bg_pressed.xml as follows

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
  android:startColor="#FFA500"
  android:endColor="#FFA500"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```